# Add some hooks to Twitter Bootstrap's modal dialog

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a video inside a modal, which can be opened through many links across the page.

The problem is, when I close the modal with the video running, I can still hear the video... which makes sense, but I don't want it.

Is there a way to implement a hook in Bootstrap's events, like modal? Some event or other thing that allow me to stop the video when the modal is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle either `hide` or `hidden` event* which modal is triggering before and after close respectively.

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {
    // stop the video playback
});
```

**[**Here*](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)** are all supported events and methods.